# Remove label message on keydown

Tags: javascript, dom-events

My prompt is working okay, when someone leave the phone input field blank my label message shows, but how do I remove the message, when they go back to the input field on click down?

```js
function validatePhone(){
            var phone  = document.getElementById("phone1").value;
            if(phone.length === 0) {
                console.log("phone number is required.");
                producePrompt("Phone number is required.", "messagePrompt", "red");
                return false;
            } 
        }


        function producePrompt(message, promptLocation, color) {
            document.getElementById(promptLocation).innerHTML = message;
            document.getElementById(promptLocation).style.color = color;
        }
```

```css
    form {
        width: 30em;
        height: 10em;
        position: absolute;
        left: 50%;
        top: 50%;
        transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
        background: #2c3e50;
    }

    form input {
        text-align: left;
        padding-left: 5px;
        margin: 0 0 10px 15px;
        position: relative;
        
        }

    form label {
        text-align: center;
    }

    #messagePrompt {
        color: red;
```

```html
<form>
        <p>Please enter your phone number below:</p>
        <input name="phone1" id="phone1" placeholder="(000)000-0000" />
        <label for="" id="messagePrompt"></label>
        <br>
        <input type="button"  value="send message" onclick="validatePhone()"  />
    </form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just add function on ur input label to remove_msg

```js
function validatePhone(){
   var phone  = document.getElementById("phone1").value;
   if(phone.length === 0) {
    console.log("phone number is required.");
    producePrompt("Phone number is required.", "messagePrompt", "red");
    return false;
   } 
  }


  function producePrompt(message, promptLocation, color) {
   document.getElementById(promptLocation).innerHTML = message;
   document.getElementById(promptLocation).style.color = color;
  }

function remove_msg(){
    producePrompt(" ", "messagePrompt", "red");

}
```

```css
 form {
  width: 30em;
  height: 10em;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  background: #2c3e50;
 }

 form input {
  text-align: left;
  padding-left: 5px;
  margin: 0 0 10px 15px;
  position: relative;
  
  }

 form label {
  text-align: center;
 }

 #messagePrompt {
  color: red;
    }
```

```html
<form>
  <p>Please enter your phone number below:</p>
  <input name="phone1" id="phone1" placeholder="(000)000-0000" onclick="remove_msg()" />
  <label for="" id="messagePrompt"></label>
  <br>
  <input type="button"  value="send message" onclick="validatePhone()"  />
</form>
```

Answer (score 2):

If you can use jQuery this becomes very easy:

```
$('#phone1').mousedown(function() {
    $('#messagePrompt').remove();
});
```

Or, possibly just remove the prompt when focus is given to the input 
field so keyboard navigation works as well:

```
$('#phone1').focusin(function() {
    $('#messagePrompt').remove();
});
```

If you don't want to actually *remove* the label and just have it be blank you can replace the remove() call with:

```
$('#messagePrompt').text('');
```

- https://api.jquery.com/remove/
- https://api.jquery.com/focusin/
- https://api.jquery.com/mousedown/